# Is it possible to automate tags / tagging of new files dropped into a specific folder?

Tags: macos, automator, automation, finder-tag

Is it possible to automate tagging of new files dropped into a specific folder?

Answer (score 1):

I use Hazel tool to automatically define tags when files added to specific folders.

http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel